# HDMI API for Asus Transformer (and others)

Tags: android, api, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Currently HDMI outputs are handled by proprietary APIs. [Motorola's](http://developer.motorola.com/docs/motorola-hdmi-dual-screen-api/) is the easiest to find, but where is the similar API for the other manufacturers? I'm most interested in Transformer Prime but Samsung and LG also have HDMI outs.

Comment: Note: Motorola's API is deprecated since the original post.